# Vue accessing loop index within input name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue2 to loop through a data set and need to access the index within the input elements attribute as shown below. The problem is I am not binding to vue data entirely but just need the index. And using the colon syntax to bind will look for email within the vue data, which I don't want/need.

Currently, I am getting the following error:

```
Interpolation inside attributes has been removed.
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

```
<div>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12" v-for="(item, index) in contact.emails">
          <input :value="item.email" name="emails[{{ index }}][email]" />
```

Comment: item is overloaded, both loops define it. On purpose?

Comment: Please see edited, it should just be a single loop.

Comment: so you want to bind the inputs to the property named "email" of each array element of contact.emails?

Comment: I simply want the name attr values to be: `emails[0][email]`, `emails[1][email]`, `emails[2][email]`, etc. and 'email' is a string

Comment: `:name="'emails[' + index + '][email]'"`